# .animate() or .click() function not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've got a `fullScreen()` function that currently works on Chrome and Microsoft Edge by manipulating a div's CSS left attribute to either 0 or -100%. Here is the jQuery:

```
var fullScreen = function() {
    $('#fullscreenbutton').click(function() {
        $('.dashboard').animate({
            left: "-100%" 
        }, 200);
    });
    $('#hamburgerbutton').click(function() {
        $('.dashboard').animate({
            left: "0" 
        }, 200);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="dashboard">
        <div class="navtools">
            <ul>
                <li id="searchli">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 22px;"></span></span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="findmebutton"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 22px;"></span> <p>Find Me</p></li>
                <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 22px;"></span> <p>Favorite</p></li>
                <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 22px;"></span> <%= link_to ' Back ', root_path, :class => 'none' %> </li>
                <li id="fullscreenbutton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 22px;color: #2A83C6"></span> <p>Full Screen</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='myMap' oncontextmenu="return false">
        <div class="hamburgerbutton">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" id="hamburgerbutton" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px;"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
          <a href="#" class="close" style="padding-left: 10px" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
          <strong>Hey!</strong> Right-click or hold to add a location.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions or point in the right direction?

Comment: who is calling `fullScreen`

Comment: Sorry Arun, I'm confused by the question. Any user is calling fullScreen when they click the "#fullscreenbutton" which is simply a li item. When the li item is clicked the .dashboard div which is absolute positioned over the Bing Map is moved left -100% (on chrome and IE) out of the screen. Then to pull the dashboard back on the screen a user clicked the #hamburgerbutton which i believe is just an image i placed in a div absolute positioned top left of the Bing Map.

Comment: i've included the HTML in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding it in a function call, do bindings in Dom ready block and it can be simplified as:

```
 $(function (){
      $('#fullscreenbutton, #hamburgerbutton').click(function (){           
           $('.dashboard').animate({
                  left: this.id === 'fullscreenbutton' ? "-100%" : "0"
            }, 200);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Jai! This seems to work. Can you explain why this is different or better then the function i created? I would like to understand better why this works compared to my solution.

Comment: @alecs36 Anyone should not bind the events in a function call. what that does is it binds new events whenever you call that function. This is same as like, you have your bindings in a function and you call that function in DOM ready event. So, instead of doing it other way round it should be done in the dom ready block.